# Memoizing on some of a functions arguments in Python

Tags: python, caching

Suppose I have a function that takes an object representing a web browser and uses it to grab a web page. I might be following that URL again at some point in the program, and I'd prefer to have the page cached to loading it again. But the trick is, I might be using a different browser object at that point. I'm happy to get the value from the cache, but lru_cache (and most other memoization systems) will consider the two invocations different by virtue of the different browser arguments. I'm wondering if there's a nice way to use memoization while ignoring some of the functions arguments. What I've got below is neither nice nor reusable.

```
from functools import lru_cache


class Browser(object):
    """Pretend this is a Browser from mechanize"""

    count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.count = Browser.count
        Browser.count += 1
        print("Created browser #{}".format(self.count))

    def get_url(self, url):
        """Pretend we're actually doing something here"""
        print("...Browser #{} visiting {}".format(self.count, url))
        return url[::-1] 


@lru_cache()
def _get_url(url):
    return _get_url.browser.get_url(url)
_get_url.browser = None


def get_url(browser, url):
    _get_url.browser = browser
    return _get_url(url)


for url in "www.python.org www.yahoo.com www.python.org".split():
    browser = Browser() # Imagine that we periodically switch to a different Browser instance
    print("{} => {}".format(url, get_url(browser, url)))
```

Output:

```
Created browser #0
...Browser #0 visiting www.python.org
www.python.org => gro.nohtyp.www
Created browser #1
...Browser #1 visiting www.yahoo.com
www.yahoo.com => moc.oohay.www
Created browser #2
www.python.org => gro.nohtyp.www
```

Comment: You could use `functools.partial` to curry the browser into a unary `get_url()`; this would prevent your dependence on the module-scoped `_get_url_browser`. This effectively codes around the limitation of `@lru_cache` which was written to cache by all arguments to the wrapped function.

Comment: @msw, I can get a `partial` of `get_url` and then feed that `partial` to `lru_cache`. The problem is what to do when I need to switch to a need `Browser` instance. I can create a new `partial` using the new `Browser` but the `lru_cache` is still pointing at the old `partial`. I can modify the original `partial` object to use a different `Browser` but that's pretty gross.

Comment: yep, I agree. Giving a new Browser a persistent cache instance would make for a cleaner structure. Thinking through it, a Browser should definitely have a get_url() method, and it can simply check for a cached entry or cache the one it retrieves; this effectively makes the cache a hidden implementation detail. Put another way, I want my Browser to yield pages and not bother me with internal optimizations.